# How to tell gradle to use the wrapper if it's present?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

Is there a global configuration option for `gradle` so that it will use the gradle wrapper if `gradlew` is present?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
gradle() {
        if [ -f ./gradlew ]; then
                ./gradlew "$@"
        else
                command gradle "$@"
        fi
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently using, but it feels like this should be built in to gradle, and configurable in e.g. `~/settings.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

You could install and use `gdub` (https://github.com/dougborg/gdub). This will use the gradle wrapper if found for the project, or use globally installed gradle if not found.

Installing it was literally just two lines of code:

```
$ curl -sLo- http://get.bpkg.sh | bash
$ bpkg install dougborg/gdub -g
```

And use it like this:

```
$ gw build
```